# Is there a way to assign multiple variables for one input box - Python

Tags: python, input, python-3.3

How would I assign multiple variables to one GUI input box? Something like this: q1, q2, q3 = input()

This isn't how the code would go, but this is just something I want it to be like:

```
 a, b, c = str(input("Type in a command"))
```

But not like this:

```
abc = str(input("Type in a command"))

if abc == str("a"):
    print ("a is right")
else:
    print ("a is wrong")

if abc == str("b"):
    print ("b is right")
else:
    print ("b is wrong")

if abc == str("c"):
    print ("c is right")
else:
    print ("c is wrong")
```

If I did it this way, I'd get one of them wrong and it will tell me that one is right & 2 are wrong. (a is wrong, b is right, c is wrong)

Comment: why do you need str() around the input?

Comment: When I enter a command into the input box, it reads it as a string instead of just a number.

Comment: @JakeLeduc I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm pretty sure that `str` doesn't do anything if this is the code you are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

`input` can only return one string, but you can process it on the fly:

```
a, b, c = input('Type in a command').split()
```

This may result in `ValueError` if the number of "words" in the input differs from 3, so you may want to use `try`-`except` to handle it.

```
try:
    a, b, c = input('Type in a command').split()
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input. Please enter a, b and c')
```

Answer (score 2):

`Input` returns only a single string. You can store the input and then process it as per your needs. A simple and safe way to take multiple variable input is :

```
s = input().split()
```

Here, `s` gives you a list of your whitespace separated inputs. This can take in **any number** of options.

You can then process **each** individually :

```
for i in s :
    if i in ('a','b','c') : 
        print(i, " is right")
    else :
        print(i, " is wrong")
```

Comment: I really don't understand the logic behind a downvote without a supporting comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different types, you could probably use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
a,b,c = ast.literal_eval("3,4,5")
a,b,c = ast.literal_eval("3,4.5,'foobar'")
```

This works because `ast` evalutes the string into a tuple which contains literals.  It is then unpacked on the left hand side.  Of course, for this to work, the elements must be separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use

```
 a = b = c = str(input("Type in a command"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).